# Refresh data in CollectionView does not work Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to refresh the Collection View when segue from another view, but it does not working, and it never get into the collectionView func anymore? Did i do anything wrong here? Thanks

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var notesTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseName: UILabel!

var collectionView: UICollectionView? 
var listOfExerciseItems:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfExerciseItems.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as colvwCell
    cell.exerciseName.text = listOfExerciseItems[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your AddViewController as the delegate and the datasource of your collectionView in viewDidLoad.

You actually don't need to reloadData when performing a segue.

I think your collectionView is incorrectly set. It should be an IBOutlet.